# coldfusion removeHtml outputs latin text incorrectly. Is there a better way?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a trim function which works fine with English text, but if that same function reads Spanish text with accents etc it strips out all the accents instead. Is there a better way to trim the output?

For example, if the text from MySQL is 'hello and good morning' it outputs fine and trims it correctly, but if my the text is 'hola y buenos días' it trims it, but also strips out the 'í' in the word días.

The code I'm using is:

```
<cfif trim(getProps.property_description) gt "">
      #formatTeaser(removeHtml(getProps.property_description),290)#… 
      [<a href="">#lang_more#</a>]
</cfif>
```

I have also added this to the page the code, but it has made no difference:

```
<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="utf-8" />
```

The MySQL field is set up as `varchar` and displays correctly on other pages when I don't use the trim method as above.

Comment: What does your removeHtml and formatTeaser functions look like?

Comment: you only need `<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="utf-8" />` if there is UTF-8-encoded text *in the source code itself*, and just flags the compiler to treat the CFM file as UTF-8 encoded. It does not help situations where the UTF-8-encoded text is in a variable (which is only a consideration at runtime).

Comment: removeHTML is not an internal function, so unless you show us that code we're not going to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem lays not with `trim()`, but with `removeHTML()`.

Check out [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ColdFusion_Security_Resources#OWASP_Resources). It is a Java library that you can use in your CF application to selectively filter anything unsafe/unnecessary from strings.

Peter Freitag has some nice [examples](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/788.cfm) on his blog.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't even a `RemoveHTML()` function in ColdFusion.

The UDF you probably copied off some website must be faulty. This works for me:

```
<cfscript>
function RemoveHtml(s) {
    return REReplace(s, "<[^>]+>", "", "ALL");
}
function FormatTeaser(s, i) {
    // dummy
    return s & "…";
}
</cfscript>

<cfset getProps.property_description = "<b>¡Hola y buenos días!<b>">
<cfset lang_more = "expandir">

<cfset clean_description = Trim(RemoveHtml(getProps.property_description))>
<cfif clean_description gt "">#formatTeaser(clean_description, 290)# [<a href="">#lang_more#</a>]</cfif>
```

outputs

```
¡Hola y buenos días!… [expandir]
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions to remove HTML only work some of the time, and might be what's stripping out your unicode. (Are you accepting only a-zA-Z0-9?) To safely remove HTML, use Jsoup (http://jsoup.org/) by putting the jsoup jar in your WEB-INF/lib directory and restart the ColdFusion service.

Then create a Jsoup object

`<cfset local.jsoup = createObject( "java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup" )/>
<cfset local.whitelist = createObject( "java", "org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist" ) />
<cfset local.cleanHTML = local.jsoup.clean( arguments.html, local.whiteList.none()/>`

That's it, local.cleanHTML is your cleaned text. Then run your other functions on that. If there is still a problem, show us your FormatTeaser method.

Answer (score -2):

I finally used an enhanced version of left()

you can find it here, it trims the data without any issues…
http://cflib.org/udf/FullLeft

Comment: This might have got you moving on, but it's not an answer to the question you actually asked.